# Crystal Reports - Removing duplicates in 2 data fields

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have 2 data fields base on 2 xml files in my Crystal Report.

---

**First data field is - EXP**

> ```
> TRANSID     EXPID    PAYMENT     MONTH
> trans01     exp01    1,000.00   JANUARY
> trans02     exp02    2,000.00   JANUARY
> ```

**Second data field is - FEE**

> ```
> TRANSID    FEEID    PAYMENT      MONTH
> trans03    fee01    3,000.00    JANUARY
> trans04    fee02    4,000.00    JANUARY
> trans05    fee03    5,000.00    JANUARY
> ```

---

My expected output is this:
**(I want this to happen)**

> ```
> For the month of: January
>
>              EXP                                  FEE
>
> TRANSID     EXPID    PAYMENT          TRANSID    FEEID     PAYMENT
> trans01     exp01    1,000.00         trans03    fee01    3,000.00
> trans02     exp02    2,000.00         trans04    fee02    4,000.00
>                                       trans05    fee03    5,000.00
> ```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

---

But the output is this:

> ```
> For the month of: January
>
>              EXP                                  FEE
>
> TRANSID     EXPID    PAYMENT          TRANSID    FEEID     PAYMENT
> trans01     exp01    1,000.00         trans03    fee01    3,000.00
> trans02     exp02    2,000.00         trans03    fee01    3,000.00
> trans01     exp01    1,000.00         trans04    fee02    4,000.00
> trans02     exp02    2,000.00         trans04    fee02    4,000.00
> trans01     exp01    1,000.00         trans05    fee03    5,000.00
> trans02     exp02    2,000.00         trans05    fee03    5,000.00
> ```

Comment: You need to create two subreports - Exp and Fee and place them side by side to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Insert a Subreport that points to the "Fee" table. Drag and drop the fields you need on the Details Section on this Subreport
> 2. Place this Subreport on the Report Header
> 3. Go to the Section Expert > Select Report Header > Check 'Underlay following sections"
> 4. Place fields you need from the Exp table on the Details Section of the Main Report.